# Transpose date in excel to include header row

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have data as below which records players name and number of goals kicked per round.  Blanks mean they didnt play the x means they played but didnt kick a goal.

```
Surname | First | Second | R1 | R2 | R3 | R4 | R5|
Smith   | Barry | John   | x  |    |    |    | 2 |
Jones   | Murry | Fred   | x  |  3 |  2 |  1 | 2 |
Wills   | Geoff | Mike   | x  |    |    |  x | x |
```

And Need it to display like:

```
Smith | Barry | John | R1 | x |
Smith | Barry | John | R5 | 2 |
Jones | Murry | Fred | R1 | x |
Jones | Murry | Fred | R2 | 3 |
Jones | Murry | Fred | R3 | 2 |
Jones | Murry | Fred | R4 | 1 |
Jones | Murry | Fred | R5 | 2 |
Wills | Geoff | Mike | R1 | x |
Wills | Geoff | Mike | R4 | x |
Wills | Geoff | Mike | R5 | x |
```

So far I have this code in VBA

```
Sub NewLayout()
    For i = 2 To Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        For j = 0 To 4
        If Cells(i, 4 + j) <> vbNullString Then
            intCount = intCount + 1
            Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(intCount, 10)
            Cells(i, 2).Copy Destination:=Cells(intCount, 11)
            Cells(i, 3).Copy Destination:=Cells(intCount, 12)
            Cells(i, 4 + j).Copy Destination:=Cells(intCount, 13)
        End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which is getting me most of what I need without returning the header row ie R1, R2, R3 etc..

Comment: apology not sure how to display the table in a neat format

Comment: see second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Comment: Use Power Query.  Select the first three columns, then **unpivot other columns** *(assuming many of your "value" entries in your results table are erroneous. If not you need to explain the logic behind them)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify your code, you can change your last `copy` line slightly, and add a line to copy the relevant header row

```
        Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(intcount, 10)
        Cells(i, 2).Copy Destination:=Cells(intcount, 11)
        Cells(i, 3).Copy Destination:=Cells(intcount, 12)
        Cells(1, 4 + j).Copy Destination:=Cells(intcount, 13)
        Cells(i, 4 + j).Copy Destination:=Cells(intcount, 14)
```

But I would suggest using `Power Query`, where all you have to do is

- select the first three columns
- **Unpivot other columns**

That can be done from the UI but here is the M-Code

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Surname", "First", "Second"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks Ron - I've just added the extra row into the VBA which has worked a treat as I am not familiar with Power Query.